# ActiveX Image Word select from excel?

Tags: excel, word-template, vba

I want to copy image to ActiveX image control in word.

I thought that can be done via .InlineShapes(index), but I have only name of the control..

```
Private Sub CommandButton13_Click()


 Dim intNoOfRows

 Dim intNoOfColumns

 Dim objWord

 Dim objDoc

 Dim objRange

 Dim objTable

Dim s As Word.InlineShape
Dim shp As Shape
intNoOfRows = 4

intNoOfColumns = 2

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

Set objRange = objDoc.Range

objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns

Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)

objTable.Borders.Enable = True



  objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture UserForm1.txtImageLogo
  objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
  objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture   UserForm1.txtImageLogoClient






objTable.Cell(2, 1).Merge MergeTo:=objTable.Cell(2, 2)

objTable.Cell(2, 1).Height = 520

With objWord
Set s = objTable.Cell(2,  1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(UserForm1.txtImageBackground)
s.Height = 510
s.Width = 460


End With

  objTable.Cell(3, 1).Merge MergeTo:=objTable.Cell(3, 2)
   objTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Prepared by:" & "  " & UserForm1.txtPrepared
   objTable.Cell(4, 1).Merge MergeTo:=objTable.Cell(4, 2)
   objTable.Cell(4, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
  objTable.Cell(4, 1).Range.Text = "Belgrade," & " " & Format(Date, "MMMM DD, YYYY ")


  Set objTable = Nothing


  End Sub
```

So, I've managed to insert table into word, everything is OK, but I just need to put backgroundImage behind text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the Image control in Developer/Controls/Legacy Tools/ActiveX:

```
Dim ax As MsForms.Image
Set ax = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat.Object
ax.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg")
```

You need to access the OLEFormat.Object of an InlineShape in order to address its public COM properties and methods. The legacy ActiveX controls are actually UserForm controls, so if you declare it using strict typing you'll get Intellisense. You can also Dim as Object, but then there's no Intellisense.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've go an error : run-time error '-2147418113' (8000fffff) Catastrophic failure Automation error.  It's not necessary  to be an activeX image control, I just need 3 pictures to insert to word, to pass the word path to the pictures, and to choose where I want to put them (via bookmarks, or table). Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've managed some of my idea to action. Please review my post. The last thing I want now is to put image behindText. I need to convert it to shape object. But I dont know how from there. Thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking for Shape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind